# Can't type in password for Steam Install on Ubuntu

Tags: password, steam

I just got Steam from the Ubuntu Software Center, and it asked me to reopen steam to finish the installation.  When I opened it up, I got a terminal that said the following:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for michael:
```

When I go to type in my password in the terminal, it isn't registering that I am typing my password in and it is staying blank. I tried a fresh terminal window to see if I could type in that one and I could, and everywhere else I can type except for the Steam install terminal which is called "Package Install".

I have tried to reset my machine a couple of times to see if that would fix the problem and it didn't. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

Terminal dosn't show key presses, or stars for password. (So you won't *see* it typed, it will seem like nothing is happening, this is a security feature so others can not know the length of the password)

So keep typing and then hit enter once you have entered your password.

Also note: This will be your Ubuntu system password.

**If the install fails you may want to install the packages Steam says it needs through the software center or synaptic package manager.**

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same problem on Debian. This is not about hidden password input. The terminal doesn't response to Enter either. The solution is to close the window and install required packages manually:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386
```

Then launch `steam` again, and the terminal won't appear.